# How to download file client-side using Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following code, which allows me to download a json file client-side, working perfectly in Safari and Chrome:

```
function downloadObjectAsJson(exportObj, exportName){
  var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + 
  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(exportObj));
  var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", exportName + ".json");
  downloadAnchorNode.click();
  downloadAnchorNode.remove();
}
```

But in Firefox nothing happens. There is no error or warning. Just nothing. Is there something about the above code that Firefox cannot utilize?

Comment: Have you tried appending the element to the DOM first?

Comment: Yes, still nothing.

Answer (score 3):

A few months old but still, here is the solution that worked for me :

```
    const fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file); 
    const link = document.createElement('a'); 
    link.setAttribute('href', fileUrl); 
    link.setAttribute('download', filename); 
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank'); 
    document.body.appendChild(link); //Required for Firefox 
    link.click(); 
    link.remove(); 
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileUrl);
```

You're missing the `document.body.appendChild(link); //Required for Firefox`part. With it, all should be fine